# Web app ui is working strange in specific mobile browser

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-web

I had used “flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release” for creating build
[image: 1]

Comment: On which browser do you face these issues? We face similar problems with the Instagram In-App-Browser. Have you tried changing the web renderer to html?